# get age in years for month of july

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores the date of birth of patients in DateTime format(2022-06-22).

How can I get the age in years for people born in July?

I have tried the below:

```
select sFirstName,
sLastName,
dDateOfBirth,
DATEDIFF(yy,dDateOfBirth,GETDATE()) as Age,
ifkMedicalAidID
from Patients
where DATEDIFF(month,dDateOfBirth,GETDATE()) between 5 and 5
```

Although I get only all the records for July(which is correct) all the ages are 0, I see the problem with the above query but I don't have the SQL knowledge to resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(DAY,0,dDateOfBirth)) / 365.2425) AS AgeYears
```

Answer (score -2):

this did the trick   thanks John

```
select sFirstName,
    sLastName,
    dDateOfBirth,
    DATEDIFF(yy,dDateOfBirth,GETDATE()) as Age,
    ifkMedicalAidID
    from Patients
    where   datepart(month,dDateOfBirth)=7
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF(yy,dDateOfBirth,GETDATE()` doesn't give you someone's age. Someone born on `2021-12-31` is not `1` year old today. People age on their birthday, not when the year changes.